Django: how do I make a dependent dropdown load a filtered list of objects on the update form?
I have multiple dependent dropdowns throughout my application. To add a new record, the form works as expected; for example, you select a Country and the list of State objects for that Country will load, you then select a State and the Suburb objects for that State will load. You save the record, it has all the fields saved correctly, you view the record and all the info can be viewed all as expected.
The problem I have is when I want to change/update the record. The instantiated SuburbForm is told to first load a blank dropdown for State, and call a function load_dropdowns when the parent object Country has been set. This action of calling load_dropdowns does not seem to happen in the update form, instead it just stays blank, even if I try to re-select the parent.
If I change the instantiated form to load all objects instead of the blank dropdown, the update form fills in the field correctly, but that means the add new and update forms now load all objects instead of the filtered list.
models.py
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country")

class State(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="State")
    state_in_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Country", blank=True, null=True)

class Suburb(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Suburb")
    suburb_in_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Country", blank=True, null=True)
    suburb_in_state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="State", blank=True, null=True)

forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Country, State, Suburb

class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = [
            'item_name'
        ]

class StateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = [
            'item_name', 
            'state_in_country'
        ]

class SuburbForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # separately define fields for dependent dropdowns
    suburb_in_country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.filter(deleted=False),widget=forms.Select(attrs={"hx-get": "load_states_for_suburbform/", "hx-target": "#id_suburb_in_state"}),label="Country")

    # THE FOLLOWING VARIABLE RESULTS IN A BLANK DROPDOWN LIST WHICH CHANGES TO A FILTERED LIST ON ADD NEW FORM BUT REMAINS BLANK ON UPDATE FORM - SEE __init__ BELOW
    suburb_in_state = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=State.objects.none(),label="State")
        
    class Meta:
        model = Suburb
        fields = [
            'item_name', 
            'suburb_in_country',
            'suburb_in_state'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuburbForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # handle input from dependent dropdowns
        if 'suburb_in_country' in self.data:
            suburb_in_country = int(self.data.get("suburb_in_country"))
            self.fields['suburb_in_state'].queryset = State.objects.filter(state_in_country=suburb_in_country)     

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from .forms import *
from .models import *

...
def update(request, id, item):
    item = str_to_class(item)
    page_title = 'Update ' + item._meta.verbose_name
    instance = get_object_or_404(item, id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = str_to_class(item._meta.verbose_name.strip() + 'Form')(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect(item._meta.list_view)
    else:
        form = str_to_class(item._meta.verbose_name.strip() + 'Form')(instance=instance)
                     

    context = {'form':form, 
               'title': page_title,
               'list_view': item._meta.list_view}

    return render(request, 'create.html', context)
...
# Load data for dropdowns that depend on the choice of parent item
# requires model name (item) and the parent field to filter on (parent_field)
def load_dropdowns(request, item, parent_field):
    parent_id = 0 if request.GET.get(parent_field) in (None, '') else request.GET.get(parent_field) 
    if parent_id == 0:
        # parent item has not yet been chosen (or blank has been selected)
        return render(request, "emptydropdown.html")
    
    if item == State:
        # parent item of State is Country
        # show only states belonging to the chosen country
        items = State.objects.filter(state_in_country_id=parent_id, deleted=False).order_by('item_name')
    
    if item == Suburb:
        # parent item of Suburb is State
        # show only suburbs belonging to the chosen state
        items = Suburb.objects.filter(suburb_in_state_id=parent_id, deleted=False).order_by('item_name')
    return render(request, 'dependentdropdown.html', context={'items': items})
...
def load_states_for_suburbform(request):
    return load_dropdowns(request, State, 'suburb_in_country')


https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Thanks, I skimmed this guide so many times and never got to the final section! It doesn't solve my issue, but I was able to use that info to solve it.

Solution is to have an additional if statement at the end of the SuburbForm:
class SuburbForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # separately define fields for dependent dropdowns
    suburb_in_country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.filter(deleted=False),widget=forms.Select(attrs={"hx-get": "load_states_for_suburbform/", "hx-target": "#id_suburb_in_state"}),label="Country")

    # THE FOLLOWING VARIABLE RESULTS IN A BLANK DROPDOWN LIST WHICH CHANGES TO A FILTERED LIST ON ADD NEW FORM BUT REMAINS BLANK ON UPDATE FORM - SEE __init__ BELOW
    suburb_in_state = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=State.objects.none(),label="State")
        
    class Meta:
        model = Suburb
        fields = [
            'item_name', 
            'suburb_in_country',
            'suburb_in_state'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuburbForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # handle input from dependent dropdowns
        if 'suburb_in_country' in self.data:
            suburb_in_country = int(self.data.get("suburb_in_country"))
            self.fields['suburb_in_state'].queryset = State.objects.filter(state_in_country=suburb_in_country)
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['suburb_in_state'].queryset = State.objects.filter(state_in_country=self.instance.suburb_in_country)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
